# Adding masonry using isotope jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I want to build a masonry based filtering portfolio page using isotope plugin same to same PSD design but it's not working. When run the code masonry is working but images height is not working. PSD's all images are the same height and different width when I will run the code it's not the same design as PSD design.

I am trying different way but it's not same to the same PSD design.

```
    [Psd portfolio design[1] design different is height---
    [output is][2]

      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia5bj.jpg
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2gad.jpg
```

Here is HTML markup:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col-md-4 grid-item bath house electric">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="">
                <figcaption>
                    <a href="images/portfolio/1.jpg"></a>
                </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 grid-item office bath paint">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/portfolio/2.jpg" alt="">
                <figcaption>
                    <a href="images/portfolio/2.jpg"></a>
                </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-4 grid-item electric paint house">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="">
                <figcaption>
                    <a href="images/portfolio/3.jpg"></a>
                </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-4 grid-item office bath electric house">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/portfolio/4.jpg" alt="">
                <figcaption>
                    <a href="images/portfolio/4.jpg"></a>
                </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-4 grid-item electric office bath paint">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/portfolio/5.jpg" alt="">
                <figcaption>
                    <a href="images/portfolio/5.jpg"></a>
                </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 grid-item paint">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/portfolio/6.jpg" alt="">
                <figcaption>
                     <a href="images/portfolio/6.jpg"></a>
                </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

Main jQuery:

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Isotope main Jquery

```
<script src="js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

Jquery activation code is

```
        $('.grid').isotope({
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          percentPosition: true,
          masonry: {
            // use outer width of grid-sizer for columnWidth
            columnWidth: '.grid-item'
          }
        })
```

Comment: you may have to add a     $( window ).load(function() {
  // Run code
});  to the isotope grid.  I recall having a similar issue with image heights not calculating properly.   or try $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('.grid').isotope({
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          percentPosition: true,
          masonry: {
            // use outer width of grid-sizer for columnWidth
            columnWidth: '.grid-item'
          }
        })
});

Comment: or you may have to give them specific classes / heights in CSS  - reference this page http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html

Comment: height: auto is used in my CSS file no window load function in my custom.js file. All day I was just trying to fixing this problem using all kind of documentation of isotope but not working

Comment: can you build it out in a codepen.  may be easier for us all to trouble shoot or see what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In your posted code, you are not loading isotope.pkgd.min.js, only imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js. In addition, you are not actually utilizing any code for imagesloaded. This is needed so that all images are loaded before isotope does its layout.
This is code that utilizes imagesloaded:

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>    

 <script>
 $( document ).ready(function() { 
 $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
    $('.grid').isotope({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      percentPosition: true,
      masonry: {
        // use outer width of grid-sizer for columnWidth
        columnWidth: '.grid-item'
      }
    });
  }); 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I am trying this code but not working it's same result image height

Comment: Without a link or jsfiddle or codepen it is a bit hard to help any more. This is pretty much standard code for isotope with imagesloaded. Are you sure all js scripts are loaded? Any errors in the console?

Comment: I updated my code. Try it again. I forgot to put a script tag around the isotope code! oops

Comment: i am using   (function($) {"use strict";    $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
    $('.grid').isotope({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      percentPosition: true,
      masonry: {
        // use outer width of grid-sizer for columnWidth
        columnWidth: '.grid-item'
      }
    });
  }); 
  });  })(jQuery);  but also try your code with external js but not working

Comment: Your code has an extra "})". Should be ````(function($) {"use strict"; $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() { $('.grid').isotope({ itemSelector: '.grid-item', percentPosition: true, masonry: {  columnWidth: '.grid-item' } }); }); });(jQuery); ````. You should make a jsfiddle or post a link.